# Helmet glass part makes hair not show for character

Tags: materials, shaders, transparency, glass, effects

I've been following a course on creating a character with Blender 2.8 and have got to a point where I should make the helmet glass part look like glass. After applying the filters to do that, the hair on my character disappears. Do you know why that might be?

**Filters for helmet glass**

[image: Helmet with transparent glass, makes hair not show]

**Filters for hair**

[image: Character without helmet, hair is visible]

Comment: You can't render multiple transparent object behind each other with EEVEE. It's a limitation of the engine. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html#screen-space-refraction

Comment: @FFeller thank you.